# vb.net import csv to sql server, how to convert the csv string value to sql table int

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, csv

I try to import csv data to sql server database table use vb.net. When I try to convert the csv string value to sql table int, I always fail. I have try to check from google but still don't find a solution.

below is my code:

```
Dim table As New DataTable()
    Dim parser As New FileIO.TextFieldParser("D:\test_1.csv")

    table.Columns.Add("STUDENT_NAME")
    table.Columns.Add("STUDENT_NO")


    parser.Delimiters = New String() {","} 
    parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
    parser.TrimWhiteSpace = True
    parser.ReadLine()

    Do Until parser.EndOfData = True
        table.Rows.Add(parser.ReadFields())
    Loop

    Dim strSql As String = "INSERT INTO TestTable STUDENT_NAME,STUDENT_NO) VALUES (@STUDENT_NAME,@STUDENT_NO)"
    Dim SqlconnectionString As String = "Server=PC_1\TESTDB;Database=test_db;User Id=testuser;Password=testuser;"
    Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(SqlconnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(strSql, connection) ' create command objects and add parameters
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@STUDENT_NAME", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15, "STUDENT_NAME")
            .Add("@STUDENT_NO", SqlDbType.Int, "STUDENT_NO")
        End With

        Dim adapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
        adapter.InsertCommand = cmd

        Dim iRowsInserted As Int32 = adapter.Update(table)

    End Using
```

Can anybody help me on this? thanks.

Comment: The only overload for `Parameters.Add` that seems to fit what you're trying to do is `.Add(parametername As String, type As SqlDBType, size As Integer, source column As String)`, so aren't you missing the `size` parameter??
What is the error you're getting?  Does it even compile??

Comment: Yes Grim, I miss the size parameter, thanks a lot for your reminding. Sorry I cannot vote for you because not enough reputation. :)

Comment: Don't worry, I've been there - very frustrating!

Comment: I find that if a cell value in the csv is blank (without any input), it will cause error when insert to the database (even if the column in database setting is allow null), any solution for it? thanks.

Comment: Probably because you're trying to convert a blank string `""` into an Integer.  That (probably) occurs long before it gets to the database.